# Resistors in series current question

Tags: current, resistors, series

[image]

According to Wikipedia, the current of resistors in series will be Vin/R1+R2. Now I could be over thinking this but is that the current that you'll get out or is that just used for determining the power of resistors or both?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider

Comment: Two issues with your question. 1) I assume you mean Vin/(R1+R2) ... don't forget the parentheses. 2) Your schematic needs to be fixed. You show V1 as  the voltage source, but also show V1 as the voltage across R1.

Comment: @Tut What I was trying to show with the "V1" on the right was the voltage across R1. V1 at the supply is just there by default with circuitlab. Sorry for the mix up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are measuring the current through the circuit. By Ohm's Law you know the current through a resistor is proportional to the applied voltage. But what happens when you don't know the voltage across the terminals of the device (i.e. what's the voltage at the middle node of the voltage divider?).

[image]

You can figure that out simply enough if you know the current through the network. Simply combine the resistor into a single component and apply the same rules as if it were a single resistor.

$$i = \frac{V}{R_3}$$

Where

$$R_3 = R_1 + R_2$$

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was thinking but wasn't sure if it was correct since I was getting a low current output with Vin being 13v and the Req being 7k.

Comment: Well that is a large resistance, so you should expect a small current flow, namely ~2mA in that case.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are referring to this circuit:

[image: Voltage divider]

You may want to take a look at [Kirchhoff's circuit laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff's_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff.27s_current_law).

> ...is that the current that you'll get out...?

You cannot determine the current "that you'll get out" of `Vout` from the circuit shown. No current will flow to the `Vout` path, since it is an open circuit and thus the current through `R1` and `R2` will be the same. If you connect a third resistor `R3` in parallel to `R2`, the current through R1 will split up into R2 and R3 depending on the resistor values. So the said output current depends on the load that will be connected to `Vout`.

Comment: What I'm actually looking for is similar I think to what you're saying. Except have where Vout is shown in your schematic as the ground point and your positive being the at the top of R1. Will the current out be determined by I=V/R?

Comment: @BowesAndArrows, The current will be I = V/R1 in that case since you just ground that middle node; R2 will be logically removed from the circuit in that case.

Comment: I've added a schematic to show what I'm looking for. So would V1's current be 3.0mA?

Comment: I knew I should have made an answer to this question before.  You are asking this in a really weird way.  If you try to measure what you call V1, you will short that resistor.  There is a voltage difference between the two nodes you are asking about.  The CURRENT through the resistor is the same current through the entire loop.    If you want it to be different, you'll have to remove the 2nd resistor.

Comment: @ShannonStrutz Then how would you use this as a voltage divider if you would short out the resistor by merely measuring across the two nodes?

Comment: As Shannon pointed out, one can tell from the way you ask, that you seem to have some basic misconception. I recommend you read up on Kirchhoffs rules and Ohms law.

Comment: Regarding "So would V1's current be 3.0mA?" - there is no current through "V1". V1 is just an arbitrary designation you placed in parallel to R1. 3mA would be the current if you replace R2 with 0 Ohm, but that would have nothing to do with V1.